# VB.net / asp.net: Get URL without filename

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i want to set a link in VB.net dynamically to a file.
My url looks like that:

```
http://server/folder/folder2/file.aspx?get=param
```

I tried to use Request.URL but i have not found any solution to get only

```
http://server/folder/folder2/
```

without the query string and without the filename.

Please help.

Comment: So, do you want the query string as well?

Comment: no, i want "http: //server/folder/folder2/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get a relative file path using the [`Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.apprelativecurrentexecutionfilepath.aspx) instance, then work with that, using [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) class ought to help:

```
Dim relativePath = Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
Dim relativeDirectoryPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(relativePath)
```

It's worth noting that `GetDirectoryName` might transform your slashes, so you could expand the path:

```
Dim mappedPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(newpath)
```

So, to remove redundancy, we *could* shorten this:

```
Dim path = _ 
    Server.MapPath( _ 
        Path.GetDirectoryName( _ 
            Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath)))
```

But you'll need to check for possible exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

```
Dim url = Request.Url;
Dim result = String.Format(
    "{0}{1}", 
    url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority),
    String.Join(string.Empty, url.Segments.Take(url.Segments.Length - 1))
)
```

Comment: +1, nice solution, although I think it's a bit of an overuse of the String.Format statement (keep it simple: `a & b` is sufficient, there's no need for `String.Format("{0}{1}", a, b)`.)

Comment: option strict on disallows implicit conversions from system.collections.generic.ienumerable in 1 dimensional array of string

Comment: @Heinzi, feel free to update my answer with what you think is more readable.

Comment: Also, instead of a `String.Join(String.Empty...` you can use a `String.Concat(...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Uri.Host to get the computer name and then Uri.Segments (an array) to get everything up to the filename, for example:

```
var fileName = Uri.Host && Uri.Segments(0) && Uri.Segments(1)
```

This will give you: server/folder/folder2

If you have a variable number of segments, you can iterate over them and ignore the last one.

I hope that might help :)